# Android Studio: Trying to remove HTML element in webview: blank page

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-studio, webview

I am trying to remove an HTML element in webview. Here is my code. Everything compiles fine.

I have looked at other questions and none of the answers work for me.

```
// load web url
final WebView webView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementsByTagName('publicTabs')[0].style.display=\"none\"; " + "})()");
    }
});
webView.loadUrl(mUrl);
```

When I open the app on my phone, no webpage loads. Just  blank. If I remove:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementsByTagName('publicTabs')[0].style.display=\"none\"; " + "})()");
    }
});
```

the webpage loads.

Also, can someone tell me how to remove multiple HTML elements at the same time?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Android webview tutorials : [link](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/09/android-webview-tutorial-with-examples.html)

Comment: That is only for local html webpages. What I want to do is remove HTML elements from a live website before it is displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the answers: Also check if the element is a class or Id in the website. Like the one below in my code.

```
String url = "https://www.example.com";


        final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);


        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('header home_header')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('searchBottomLinks_index searchBottomLinks_internal')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('list-unstyled list-inline')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0].style.display='none'; "+
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('header home_header')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsById('header-inner')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsById('fixed-header')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('collapse navbar-collapse')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('navbar navbar-inverse sidebars')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('footer2')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('acad-slider')[0].style.display='none'; " +



                        "})()");
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and fixed it with adding "var x=" before the javascript line :

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:var x = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display='none';");
```